How to replace the body contents (but not the body tag) in BeautifulSoup?
If we have the following document:
<html>
    <body class="some classes here" id="test">
        <div id="something">This text and the div it is inside are the content</div>
        <div id="another">So is this</div>
    </body>
</html>

How can we replace only the contents of <body> without altering the attributes it has?
This code errors:
soup.body.contents.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<div class="body-content">{soup.body.contents}</div>', "html.parser"))

With this error message:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace_with'

The following code works:
soup.body.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<div class="body-content">{soup.body.contents}</div>', "html.parser"))

However it removes the <body> tag itself, leaving only the content in its place!
I have also tried:
soup.body.string = f'<div class="body-content">{soup.body.string}</div>'

But this results in the < being changed to &lt; etc, and the inner content shows None.
I have also tried:
soup.body.string.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<div class="body-content">{soup.body.contents}</div>', "html.parser"))

But that errors with:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'

Finally I have tried:
soup.body.string = BeautifulSoup(f'<div class="body-content">{soup.body.contents}</div>', "html.parser")

But that errors with:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I have managed to get something working which keeps the <body> tag and its attributes - using the following code:
attributes = ""
for attr, value in soup.body.attrs.items():
    if type(value) is list:
        value = " ".join(value)
        attributes += f'{attr}="{value}" '
soup.body.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<body {attributes}><div class="body-content">{soup.body.contents}</div></body>',"html.parser"))

But it feels a bit nasty to do it this way, and I'm sure there are probably edge-cases to code like that.
How can we properly set the contents of the <body> tag?

@stevev Unfortunately that dupe doesn't help, I'm unable to get string to work on soup.body - I have edited my question

You could join the list, clear the body and then append your content: newContent = "".join([str(x) for x in soup.body.contents]) soup.body.clear() soup.body.append(BeautifulSoup(f'<div class="body-content">{newContent}</div>', "html.parser"))

Amazing thank you! If the question gets reopened then please feel free to post an answer and I'll accept.
